# Disable auto increment for a specific column

Tags: string, date, google-sheets, drag, array-formulas

I have a Google Spreadsheets document with two columns: first a date column and then a text column (there are more columns in reality). The content of the text column ends with a number. If I select a line and drag it down to fill the next lines automatically, both values increments. If I hold down the `Ctrl` key, no value increments.

Is there a way to increment the date column but not the text column?

Comment: Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WVQV2kLgqk5l9fGh6itzpJx2st0AM5Vj17SWNbV7jo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sheets is not so versatile to possess the option to "disable auto increment for a specific column", but there are always workarounds/compromises...

- drag each column separately
- don't drag and use ArrayFormula to auto-populate cells on a go

for example dates:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(DATE(2019; 10; 30)&":"&TODAY()+1)); "dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

will populate dates between the given date (30.10.2019) and tomorrow's day. each day will be added a row with a date.

to repeat same text:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("Test 1"&SUBSTITUTE(ROW(INDIRECT("E3:E"&COUNTA(E3:E)+2))^0; 1; ))
```

will repeat given text as many times as are dates in **E** column

[image: 0]